Pair trading - history length for spread calculation
I run a pair trading system on perpetual swaps (crypto). It runs fine but there is a concept I can't figure out. The cointegration test looks fine, but when and how to chose a given history length (or number of candles) for the spread zscore modelling ?
Some pairs would yield good return on 500 historical candles, other would do it rather on 200 candles (live trading + backtest)
Why is that, how can I make it more dynamic ?

Is it due to the spread volatility ? Spread width not large enough to cover the trading fees / slippage ?
Should I run a cointegration test on several length and chose the one that provides the lowest p-values maybe ?

I've been scratching my head off aout this.
Any idea or feedback from your own expirentation is much welcome.

Use machine learning models (like decision trees) or Bayesian optimization to dynamically choose the best history length. These models can learn from the past performance of various window lengths and suggest the best one for current market conditions

You mean while live trading I should also monitor "shadow fake positions" based on different window length and then assess which one is the best ?
That's adding a lot of complexity but if that's the way to go...I'll have to find the energy to explore that option.

For the same reason I can run a profitable backtest on the cointegration of SPX and DAX with a 6 hour window, but lose money on live trades. Before running a backtest, you should be asking the question, why should a 500 candle window be profitable? (Specificity on the window size).
Backtest are used to measure an idea, not for research purposes. Otherwise you can come up with any window size to pass a backtest (over-fitting), but it will more than likely fail live.

Is it due to the spread volatility ? Spread width not large enough to cover the trading fees / slippage ?

Potentially, how would we know? I'm guessing you're trading the divergence between the spot and the perp. If true, it is probably never going to work since the exchange's market-maker will be doing exactly what you're doing but will have a better fee structure than you. You should be measuring whether trading this pair is actually possible in the first place. That is; measuring the size of their divergence and comparing it to the fees associated with entering and exiting the trade + potential slippage.

Should I run a cointegration test on several length and chose the one that provides the lowest p-values maybe ?

No, to my first point.
You should be asking the questions:
Why does this pair relationship exist? (This can potentially lead you to finding when their rate of convergence is at its greatest, which would beat spread/financing costs)
If it exists, under what conditions does it breakdown?
A simple example: Pairs trading the SPX and DAX. On average they're correlated and follow each other. If they start to diverge, you can long and short, which profits when they converge again. The cointegration of the pair breaks down when there are earnings i.e. NVDA, TSLA, GOOGL have really good/bad earnings. Or as seen today, SAP (German company) beat earnings so the DAX increased, whilst US markets declined. Trading on that event would have wiped away all profit from previous days when their relationship was strong.
General rule of thumb with pairs trading. The more obvious a pair is, it turns into an engineering/speed/fees problem (i.e. having direct market access, being a market-maker etc). So if you're wanting to go in this direction, you should be trying to find a way to reduce fees, being the first to recognise the divergence/convergence and trying to near instantaneously hedge the position before anyone else can

Hi,
First of all thanks for your feedback, I appreciate your time. However I'm not sure that answered any of my question, that's rather leading to a random direction.
I did precise that my strategy is already running successfully LIVE for several months already, so I was genuinely wondering what would be the concept that could help finding the proper window length dynamically rather than with backtest to avoid overfitting as you indeed mentioned.I'm using backtest for research purpose as well because it's my only way to do it so far but I'm eager to investigate any other idea.
Cheers.

Ps: I'm talking about pair arbitrage between two perpetual futures (not basis trading between a future and its underlying spot, this one requires much more caution regarding costs etc...)

@Sixk Ah I misread. But it still doesn’t change the key concepts of what I wrote. If you want to run a black box approach, will need a lot of data, since the data required is inversely proportional to the intuition applied to the problem. When you say “find it dynamically” that’s when you apply intuition in the problem. I.e. window size is adjusted for this vol level because slippage increases by x for every % increase in vol. You could calibrate your window size as the only free parameter using Bayesian inference and use a distribution that is similar to the shape of the possible window param

@Sixk Ah I misread. But it still doesn’t change the key concepts of what I wrote. If you want to run a black box approach, will need a lot of data, since the data required is inversely proportional to the intuition applied to the problem. When you say “find it dynamically” that’s when you apply intuition in the problem. I.e. window size is adjusted for this vol level because slippage increases by x for every % increase in vol. You could calibrate your window size as the only free parameter using Bayesian inference and use a distribution that is similar to the shape of the possible window param

I.e. log-normal or exponential since I’m guessing the PnL would gradually decrease as the window size gets larger and larger

Thanks man, I'll be honnest I'll have to understand your answer first and try to explore it, but I think I get the idea :)

if anyone interested, I updated the logic, not live yet but it seems way less sensible to the rolling window size. Here is the explanation as a picture, let me know if it's not clear:


Not only it's less sensible to the window size, but also less sensible to which asset is consedered as dependant timeseries or the independent one. Can't explain why but that's the result :)

Update 2: managing perfectly your beta neutrality (or almost neutral) changes quite a lot in the strategy performance, especially on extremely volatile pairs like small altcoins.
